# How to back to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I go back from 2nd view controller when I click on `UIBarButtonItem` using the custom segue?

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back)];
```

I have used the following code for:

```
- (IBAction)back {
    UIViewController *source=(UIViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:source animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: why you people downvote? it's for learning if some1 has issue. Answer him instead of downvoting himt

Comment: We need to know at least what special thing the custom segue is doing. For example, a push segue could be unwinded by calling [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; (I didn't downvote BTW)

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting but it's really tough to salvager anything...?

Comment: @saad i am agree with you. i don't know why some people down vote Instead of answering the question.

Comment: People downvote because this site is not for learning programming and its that the OP haven't taken the pain to read the Apple's Documentation. Also, if OP had taken few minutes searching on google about the issue, the issue would be solved there itself. Note that duplicate questions are flagged and deleted if voted as duplicate!

Comment: The downvotes are not because you don't have a legitimate problem but because you don't describe what it is and what you've tried.  Be explicit about what you want to achieve and what your code is doing instead.

Comment: @burhanuddin and you think everyone knows about apple docs who ever post question? Do tell me you did study for Apple docs when you asked that 10 questions? Apple docs don't have answer to them that's why you posted here?

Comment: Well for this question there is already an API for it in API reference, if you are saying that for ex if I am using `NSMutableString`, then I would be posting questions like **how to concat a string?**, **how to find a substring**, **how to find length** etc, this is easily found in the API reference. Also, this question is already been answered on SO, if you search. Why post duplicate questions? And you mentioned about my 10 questions, :), if you go through them you will find that the questions has been asked on stuff that are either not documented or showing unexpected results.

Comment: Main point of voting, downvoting, flagging, is to maintain the site with unique and quality questions. Although, I din't participate in voting/downvoting this question, I just happen to read the question and wanted to answer what might be the reason people downvoting it. They might have other reasons and I may be wrong, it just my own thought :). Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

instead of second line you can write:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people say, you should use for your case:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I want add that the method that you used, the **popToViewController** you should use it for to return to one specific view controller. In particular, this method pop the view controller on top of the navigation stack; you can check this and similar method for control the navigation in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW13).